# plt.pie() doesn't show the color of pies properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

This is my pie code, but the middle part of the pie looks like a beam of white light.

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(2,2),edgecolor='b')
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
_, texts=ax.pie(x=geo_df['job_#'],labels=labels,pctdistance=1.1,)
plt.setp(texts,size=2.5)
```

And this is my output.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to provide the data (geo_df['job_#'] and labels) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Do you have many more sectors with very small values so that the width of the white border is what creates the big "white" sector?

Comment: As @gherka mentioned, you probably have many very small categories. In your call to ax.pie, try adding: wedgeprops=dict(linewidth=0) to get rid of the white edges

Comment: @Benedictanjw thanks for your answer. My pie chart shows properly now but it doesn't look good because of the small fractions of pieces.

Comment: When I encountered this issue, I typically combine small categories, or group them under "Others"